# How to develop Custom ACL to a node in CQ

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, aem

Can any one help me how can i develop custom ACL to a node in CQ/AEM projects I refer these sites http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl, http://wemcode.wemblog.com/add-acl-to-node

```
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.security.*;
import javax.jcr.*;



public class ManageAccesscontrol{

public void test(){

Request.getSession(false);

JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession)session;

 AccessControlManager aMgr = jackrabbitSession.getAccessControlManager();

 // create a privilege set with jcr:all
 Privilege[] privileges = new Privilege[] 
 {    aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_ALL) };
 AccessControlList acl;
 try {
// get first applicable policy (for nodes w/o a policy)
acl = aMgr.getApplicablePolicies(path).nextAccessControlPolicy();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
// else node already has a policy, get that one
acl = aMgr.getPolicies(path)[0];
}
// remove all existing entries
 for (AccessControlEntry e : acl.getAccessControlEntries()) {
acl.removeAccessControlEntry(e);
}
// add a new one for the special "everyone" principal
acl.addAccessControlEntry(EveryonePrincipal.getInstance(), privileges);

 // the policy must be re-set
aMgr.setPolicy(path, acl);

// and the session must be saved for the changes to be applied
session.save();
}
}
```

still am unable to fix SESSION. 
If any one know about this help me  plz...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using the wrong session. You need the javax.jcr.Session.

```
import javax.jcr.security.Privilege;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.principal.EveryonePrincipal;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.JackrabbitAccessControlList;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.jackrabbit.authorization.AccessControlUtils;

javax.jcr.Session session = ...
String path = "/some/jcr/node/path";
Privilege[] privileges = AccessControlUtils.privilegesFromNames(session, new String[]{Privilege.JCR_ALL});
boolean is isAllowRule = true; // set to false for deny rule
// get the access control list
JackrabbitAccessControlList acl = AccessControlUtils.getAccessControlList(session, path);
if(AccessControlUtils.addAccessControlEntry(session, path, EveryonePrincipal.NAME, privileges, isAllowRule) {
 //success
} else {
 //failure
}
```

If you are more specific, how exactly are you trying to implement it, e.g. in a context of service component or servlet, so I can tell you also how to obtain an instance of valid javax.jcr.Session object.

**Edit** related to the comment below:

```
   Group group = (Group) userManager.getAuthorizable(groupId);
   if(group == null) {
        group = userManager.createGroup(groupId, new PrincipalImpl(groupId), groupPath);
   }
   Principal principal = group.getPrincipal();
   //same as above, but replace EveryonePrincipal.NAME with principal
   if(AccessControlUtils.addAccessControlEntry(session, path, principal, privileges, isAllowRule)) {...}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for giving reply . actually i want to give the access controls to anode with in the components group and then entire application nodes. So that i can restrict the nodes by custom programmatically code. can you suggest me any other approach for this.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to give the permissions to a specific group instead to set them on the node directly. But it's actually the same. You just have to retrieve/create the group, see my edit above.

Comment: hi in the above edit where can i give realtion to anode by giving path only or else we can create any node the above code itself and can you explain me about  this if line if(AccessControlUtils.addAccessControlEntry(session, path, EveryonePrincipal.NAME, privileges, isAllowRule) {
 }